# Batch script connect to ftp site and download folders + files

Tags: batch-file, authentication, ftps

What I try is to connect to a ftps site on port 55332 in passive mod via a batch script.

After the connect I will stay in the folder /photos/ and automatically download all Folders + files that contains in /photos/

That is what I have but dont know how to set the PORT: 55332 and how I can login via SSL/TLS

```
set server=xxx
set benutzername=user@xxx.yyy
set passwort=xxxxxx
set lokalerpfad="C:\destination"
set entfernterpfad=/photos/
echo open %server%>ftpcmd.dat
echo %benutzername%>>ftpcmd.dat
echo %passwort%>>ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>>ftpcmd.dat
echo literal PASV>>ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd %lokalerpfad%>>ftpcmd.dat
echo cd %entfernterpfad%>>ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo !del /q %lokalerpfad%>>ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -i -s:ftpcmd.dat
del ftpcmd.dat
```

After the ftp site login I would use the script from this thread, more specifically the answers from "Mofi" ...
[Copy folders and store them in text file to exclude once copied folders on next run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644687/copy-folders-and-store-them-in-text-file-to-exclude-once-copied-folders-on-next)

Is that possible what I imagine ?
If so help would be nice and thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows `ftp.exe` only supports plain ftp.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `open <servername> <portnumber>`:

```
echo open %server% 55332>ftpcmd.dat
```

However, assuming you're using the FTP client that ships with Windows, this still will not work given your scenario.  `ftp.exe` does not support FTP over SSL/TLS.  It supports plain FTP and that's it.  You'll need to use a client such as WinSCP, which is scriptable.