# Batch - Find string in text file and delete full line

Tags: string, file, batch-file, text

I use the script from this Thread [accepted answer from Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644687/copy-folders-and-store-them-in-text-file-to-exclude-once-copied-folders-on-next). The script copy folders and store them in text file to exclude once copied folders on next run.

Sometimes I have folders called `[incomplete]-different.names` and I do not want to copy this folders. I want that all folders with the string `[incomplete]-` and the name behind are skipped or are not even written in the text file `%CurrentList%` for further processing.

These are my previous attempts but so far I could not get up and running with the script from the top.
Help would be nice, and thanks in advance.

**Try 1:**

`for /f  "delims=" [incomplete]-%%D in ("%CurrentList%") do (
    set str=%%D
    set str=!str: =!
    set str=!str: %%D =!
    echo !str!`

**Try 2:**

`findstr /v /b /c:"[incomplete]-"%%D" "%CurrentList%" del "%%D"`

Comment: `findstr` uses regular expressions and `[` and `]` are regular expression characters.    Without seeing examples of what you are trying to filter out then we don't know what characters need to be handled.  Alternatively, `find.exe` is a simpler filter.  But without accurate information you will often not get good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close with your second attempt.

If all you want is to delete lines in %CurrentList% that contain the string `[incomplete]-`, you can just direct the output of a `findstr /v` to a temp file and then overwrite CurrentList with that file.

```
findstr /v /c:"[incomplete]-" "%CurrentList%" >tmpList.txt
move /y tmpList.txt "%CurrentList%" >nul
```